# Receiving a NullPointerException when calling a cursor in Android

Tags: java, sql, android, cursor, android-contentprovider

I am creating an application which tracks the users location using GPS, stores the longitude and latitude in a database using a content provider then output the first long and lat to a mapview.

I am able to create the cursor using this line of code:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(GPSContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                      null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

However, when I make a call to move to the first row in the database or even try to close the cursor using `c.close();` I receive a `NullPointerException`.

Edit: Just to make it clear, I can store the longitude, latitude and time in milli's within the database, the problem is then taking the data out of the database and displyaing this on a map.

#### Updated code:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "application.android.prototype";
// followed by the CONTENT_URI
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.
                    parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/gpspoints");
```

#### Updated permissions:

```
<provider android:name="GPSDataContentProvider" android:authorities="application.android.prototype">
</provider>
```

Comment: I would recommend utilizing the `Log` class and leaving debug statements to get a better idea where the NPE is coming from.

Comment: with 4 `null` s, I guess it is kind of expected :)
What is the ContentResolver your class? What does the docs of the query method say?

Comment: Bozho, yes, the ContentResolver is pointing to my ContentProvider in the GPSContentProvider class.

Comment: Check your ContentResolver, there might be raised the error. Also check permissions.

Comment: Pentium10 - I have included the following in the applications manifest file

<provider android:name="GPSDataContentProvider"
android:authorities="application.android.prototype"></provider>

Comment: What's the authority (in your code) ?
And the CONTENT_URI ?
The information you've provided is not enough to identify the problem.

Comment: dltmilano - below is the authority

public static final String AUTHORITY = "application.android.prototype";
    
followed by the CONTENT_URI

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/gpspoints");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided against using the ContentProvider in the end as my application's database is only going to be used by that single application.

Instead, I created a typical database using SQL and used a similar Cursor function:

SQLiteDatabase db = waypoints.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            return cursor;